# How do I get css counters to continue

Tags: css

The counter is not continuing numbering, I would expect the second li (DEFINITIONS) to have number 2 but it continues the numbering of the nested ol so it has the number 1.2 instead of 2:

```css
  list--sub-decimal {
    counter-reset: decimal;
    > li:before {
      counter-increment: decimal;
      content: counters(decimal, ".", decimal) " ";
    }
  }
```

```html
  <ol class="list--none">
    <li>
      <ol class="list--sub-decimal">
        <li class="subItem"><strong>DEFINITIONS</strong></li>
          <ol class="list--sub-decimal">
           <li class="subItem"><strong>"Agreement"</strong> blaa</li>
          </ol>
        <li class="subItem"><strong>DEFINITIONS</strong></li>
      </ol>
     </li>
   </ol>
```

**Thanks!!**

Comment: The css should start with a `.` Also, you use both a counter system and the li's own list-style, is that by design?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start by writing valid HTML for stuff like this to work.

Your second `<ol class="list--sub-decimal">` is not properly wrapped inside a `li`, but is a child of the `ol` above it - which is not allowed.

Once you fix that, it works:

```css
.list--sub-decimal {
  counter-reset: decimal;
 }
 .list--sub-decimal > li:before {
    counter-increment: decimal;
    content: counters(decimal, ".", decimal) " ";
 }
```

```html
<ol class="list--none">
  <li>
    <ol class="list--sub-decimal">
      <li class="subItem"><strong>DEFINITIONS</strong>
        <ol class="list--sub-decimal">
          <li class="subItem"><strong>"Agreement"</strong> blaa</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="subItem"><strong>DEFINITIONS</strong></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Almost....! It should be 2.1 not 2.2